# How to set class property's value to be set to generated id value of another class on insertion to database?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have a bit of a hard time putting this just in words, so I'll use some code to help explain myself and my problem.
So imagine I have two classes `ClassA` and `ClassB`:

```
class ClassA
{
    public int ClassAId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

[Owned]
class ClassAOwned
{
    public int ClassAId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

class ClassB
{
    public int ClassBId { get; set; }
    public string Action { get; set; }
    public ClassAOwned ClassA { get; set; }
}
```

as you can see `ClassB` contains `ClassA`, but I have another class for it `ClassAOwned` because I want `ClassB` to own `ClassA` (flatten its columns into `ClassB` table), but also have `ClassA` DbSet as a seperate table (and as I understand entity class cannot be owned and have its own DbSet at the same time), so I had to use 2 different classes. Here's my context to make it easier to understand:

```
class TestContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<ClassA> ClassAs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ClassB> ClassBs { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseInMemoryDatabase("TestContext");
    }
}
```

Now my problem comes when I'm trying to insert `ClassA` and `ClassB` to context at the same time and have to match their `ClassAId` values which is generated by database provider:

```
var testContext = new TestContext();
var classA = new ClassA
{
    Name = "classAName"
};
var classB = new ClassB
{
    Action = "create",
    ClassA = new ClassAOwned
    {
        ClassAId = classA.ClassAId,
        Name = classA.Name
    }
};
testContext.ClassAs.Add(classA);
testContext.ClassBs.Add(classB);
classB.ClassA.ClassAId = classA.ClassAId;
testContext.SaveChanges();
```

when using `InMemoryDatabase` the following call:

```
testContext.ClassAs.Add(classA);
```

actually changes `classA.ClassAId` to correct generated value, however when using SQL server `classA.ClassAId` gets set to `int.MinValue` so next call:

```
classB.ClassA.ClassAId = classA.ClassAId;
```

sets `classB.ClassA.ClassAId` to `int.MinValue`. and the final call:

```
testContext.SaveChanges();
```

changes `classA.ClassAId` to correct generated value, but `classB.ClassA.ClassAId` stays as `int.MinValue` and that's the value that gets inserted into the database.

My question is: Is there a way to tell EF core that when adding two entities into context set one's property to whatever value was generated for another entity's primary key? So the functionality I'm looking for is exactly the same as adding two entities where one has a foreign key, except in this case it's not really a foreign key.

A simple workaround would be to set the "foreign key"(`classB.ClassA.ClassAId`) after `testContext.SaveChanges()` and save changes again, but then it becomes two separate operations and what if the second one fails? The database will be in invalid state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible, but with some trickery which works with the latest at this time EF Core 2.2, and might stop working in 3.0+ (at least needs to be verified).

First, it *has* to be mapped as relationship - there is just no other way. It doesn't need to be a real database relationship though, just should be such from the EF Core model point of view.

Second, and this is quite important, the delete cascade behavior should be set to  `Restrict`, which currently means enforce in the database, but *do nothing* with the tracked related entities in memory.

So let's do that with you sample. Both aforementioned mappings require fluent configuration similar to this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ClassB>().OwnsOne(e => e.ClassA)
    .HasOne<ClassA>().WithMany() // (1)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict); // (2)
```

If you are using migrations, the generated migration would contain something like this:

```
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
    migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
        name: "ClassA",
        columns: table => new
        {
            ClassAId = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
                .Annotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn),
            Name = table.Column<string>(nullable: true)
        },
        constraints: table =>
        {
            table.PrimaryKey("PK_ClassA", x => x.ClassAId);
        });

    migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
        name: "ClassB",
        columns: table => new
        {
            ClassBId = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
                .Annotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn),
            Action = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
            ClassA_ClassAId = table.Column<int>(nullable: false),
            ClassA_Name = table.Column<string>(nullable: true)
        },
        constraints: table =>
        {
            table.PrimaryKey("PK_ClassB", x => x.ClassBId);
            table.ForeignKey(
                name: "FK_ClassB_ClassA_ClassA_ClassAId",
                column: x => x.ClassA_ClassAId,
                principalTable: "ClassA",
                principalColumn: "ClassAId",
                onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);
        });

    migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
        name: "IX_ClassB_ClassA_ClassAId",
        table: "ClassB",
        column: "ClassA_ClassAId");
}
```

Manually edit it and remove the `ForeignKey` command (line) since you don't want a real FK. You could also remove the corresponding `CreateIndex` command, although it won't hurt.

And that's all. The only *important* thing you need to remember is to use the principal `TableAId` property *only after* the new entity has been added to (thus tracked by) the context. i.e.

```
var testContext = new TestContext();
var classA = new ClassA
{
    Name = "classAName"
};
testContext.ClassAs.Add(classA); // <--
var classB = new ClassB
{
    Action = "create",
    ClassA = new ClassAOwned
    {
        ClassAId = classA.ClassAId, // <--
        Name = classA.Name
    }
};
testContext.ClassBs.Add(classB);
testContext.SaveChanges();
```

It will have generated temporary negative value, but after `SaveChanged` both ids will be updated with the actual database generated value.

Answer (score 0):

Well... As far as I  know there is no direct way to do this.

What I would suggest would be to revisit the decision to have two copies of ClassA, one that is owned and another that is independent. This is inefficient and obviously it is causing you trouble. It also creates the likelihood that the two copies will eventually get out of sync.

The obvious approach would be to have ClassA be independent and then just use "Include" to include it in the data in your queries. All the challenges you have described here will go away. Instead of trying to keep two copies of A in sync you could just create the flattened copy of B including A if/when you need it.

Comment: With the structure your are describing I can't achieve the same goals I want. `DbSet<ClassA>` will be interacted using usual CRUD, meaning `ClassA` values can change when the entity is updated. `ClassB` is for keeping history of each `ClassA` item. So using `DbSet<ClassB>` I can know exactly what each `ClassA` entity went through and what values were updated. I've thought of a couple solutions to my problem, none of them are very clean, but I just found a problem in one of those solutions interesting so I posted it here.

Comment: So what you need to do is save the history of ClassA?

Comment: @Jonny well basically yes, `ClassB` contains what action (created, updated, deleted) was taken on `ClassA`, when, by whom and what are the new values of `ClassA`. Like I've said I've figured a couple of solutions that could work, but are not very nice, but I'm mainly asking this question because I've found the problem itself interesting. Of course you can suggest solutions for history problem, you might think of something I haven't thought of.

Answer (score 0):

After getting more information, one way to implement this is something like

```
class A
{
    public int ID;
    public string data;
...
}

class HistoryA
{
    public int ID;
    public int AID;
    public string data;
    public DateTime updated;
...
}
```

So I hade one class (class A) holding the current information and another historyA referencing the current one (HistoryA.AID = A.ID) and storing all the previous information in HistoryA.

So all data properties in A was duplicated in HistoryA.